# How to temporary block everyone (including recruiters) from seeing my LinkedIn profile

Tags: linkedin

I am going to publish my CV, but without mentioning the current company, otherwise, recruiters will start to push candidates to my place before I leave. And I need to lock my LinkedIn profile which makes it possible to realize where I work even if I remove the company name there. It seems LinkedIn does not allow this...

Is there a way to do so?

It is important to guarantee that recruiters who pay LinkedIn for premium access will not be able to see my profile as well. That's the main thing about this question.

Answer (score 4):

I found this piece of advice:

> How can I disable my public profile?
>
> Please take the following steps to
>   disable your LinkedIn web profile:
>
> Log into your LinkedIn account and
>   select "Edit My Profile". Scroll down
>   to the *Public Profile URL* and select
>   "Edit". Select "None" and save your
>   changes.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your *[Public Profile Settings](http://www.linkedin.com/myprofile?editwp=)*.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to add this to company name instead:

###### Company (hidden)

and remove any detailed description for the last three experiences